# Gulp-inject transform doesn't work

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-inject

I've tried to setup gulp-inject to inject dependencies into index.html. Everything works fine except transform function. I need to replace part of  filepath in the following way: **`/frontend/src/`** --> **`/static/`** I've tried to do it like this (copy-pasted from somewhere):

```
transform : function ( filePath, file, i, length ) {
                var newPath = filePath.replace('/frontend/src', '');
                console.log('inject script = '+ newPath);
                return '<script src="/static/' + newPath  + '"></script>';
            }
```

After executing, I have nothing (except standard gulp output) in the console, and un-transformed filepath appears in result file. Looks like my custom transform just doesn't run, and the default transform works instead.

Comment: seeing your full gulpfile or task definition might help, the answer from @qcz looks good

Comment: show us your complete gulp task

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following is working for me even with multiple levels (`/**/*.js` instead of `/*.js`):

```
gulp.task('inject', function() {
    gulp.src('./test.html')
        .pipe(inject(
            gulp.src(['./Content/js/*.js'], {read: false }),
            {
                transform: function (filePath, file, i, length) {
                    var newPath = filePath.replace('/Content/js/', '');
                    console.log('inject script = '+ newPath);
                    return '<script src="/static/' + newPath  + '"></script>';
                }
            })
        )
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`gulp-inject` plugin's transform function works as intended. The configuration of the gulp task is as follows -

```
gulp.src(path.normalize('./app/index.html'))
    .pipe(inject(
        gulp.src([path.normalize('./frontend/src/*.js')], {read: false}), {
            transform : function ( filePath, file, i, length ) {
               var newPath = filePath.replace(path.normalize('/frontend/src'), '');
               console.log('inject script = '+ newPath);
               return '<script src="/static' + newPath  + '"></script>';
            }
        }
    ))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
```

To make sure it works cross-platform (Windows,Linux), [`path.normalize`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_normalize_p) is used

Check the example code at - https://github.com/pra85/gulp-inject-example